# Why size of pointed object of pointer is not zero even if we assigned pointer to NULL?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, null

I am wondering why size of object pointed by pointer is not zero even if we assigned pointer to NULL.Can anyone explain this?

compiled on g++ 4.8,ubuntu 14.04

```
Foo * foo=NULL;
cout<<"Size of pointed object of foo:"<<sizeof(*foo)<<endl;  //why it is not zero
```

Comment: Because you're asking the size of type `Foo`, not `foo`'s content.

Comment: `sizeof(*foo)` is evaluated at compile time. It simply turns into the size of a `Foo` object, regardless of what that `foo` pointer's value is when that `cout...` line runs. It's not going to do a null pointer check at runtime to see if it points anywhere.

Comment: But still foo is not pointing to any Foo object .Why it shows size of (Foo)

Comment: @RamCharan how would it know at compile time where `foo` might point to sometime at runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sizeof` is a [compile time](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sizeof-operator-c/) directive. Thus, there is no run time check to see if the pointer actually points to a real object. There is no check of the pointer at all. the directive is replaced by the compiler by the size in bytes of the type, `Foo` in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Inside `sizeof` we are in an [unevaluated context](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.context#1). Any expressions inside it will never be evaluated. `sizeof` only cares about the *type* of the expression you pass it, and the type of `*foo` is of course `Foo&`. [`sizeof` ignores the reference](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sizeof#2.sentence-1), so it returns the size in bytes that an object of type `Foo` would occupy.

Note again that the expression you wrote is never evaluated, so it does not matter whether a `Foo` object exists where `foo` points to - the value of `foo` (and the contents of the memory it points to) are of no relevance to `sizeof`.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` applies to **types**, not values. The type of `*foo` is (loosely speaking) `Foo`, so `sizeof(*foo)` is the same as `sizeof(Foo)`.